# General Solution of System Of Equations (with 3 variables)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

A system of equations is given as

```
              x + 4y +2z = 0
              3x     -2z = 4
              3x -3y -4z = 5
```

The task is to find the general solution of the system.

I wrote down the augmented matrix as follows and went on to reduce it down to row-echelon form. But, then I realized the equations are inconsistent because the rank of the system alone is 2 while the rank of the augmented matrix is 1.

Can someone give me a few pointers as to where I might have gone wrong with this and what I can do to obtain an answer?

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & -2 & 4 \\
3 & -3 & -4 & 5
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -12 & -8 & 4 \\
0 & -15 & -10 & 5
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -3 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & -3 & -2 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -3 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

EDIT : Okay, so I worked it out using elimination instead of the augmented matrix approach and got x = 4/3, y = -1/3 and z = 0, they are valid solutions but I need to find the general solution. How can I go about to find this?

Comment: Either you continue reducing it, or you start converting to algebra form: $x+4y+2z=0$, $-3y-2z=1$.

Comment: $z$ should be arbitrary because you essentially have $0z=0$. The solution should be $$\begin{align} x & = \frac{2 (z+2)}{3} & y & =-\frac{2 z+1}{3} \end{align}$$  In general you have to pick one variable as arbitrary (any of _x_, _y_ or _z_) and solve for the other two.

Comment: The system is, in fact, consistent, but it doesn’t have an unique solution.

Comment: @KennyLau That is exactly how I obtained the solutions which I mentioned in the edit.

Comment: @ja72 That seems to work here pretty well

Comment: @amd Is that so? I assumed that if the ranks of the augmented matrix doesnt match the rank of the system of equation alone, the equations are inconsistent

Comment: @AbdullahZameek The rank of both matrices is 2.

Comment: @amd Sorry, my bad ;) Youre right, they are consistent, otherrwise I wouldn't have got solutions to begin with

Answer (score 1):

You can try to continue with Gaussian elimination, but taking $z$ as a *constant* and reducing the system to a two variable problem:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{4} & \color{red}{2} & 0 \\
\color{green}{0} & \color{green}{-3} & \color{red}{-2} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right] \longrightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{4} & 0\color{red}{-2z} \\
\color{green}{0} & \color{green}{-3} & 1\color{red}{+2z} \\
  \end{array}\right]$$
Note that you need to change the sign of the column corresponding to $z$, since you are moving it to the right-hand side of the equations.

You will obtain the general solution in terms of $z$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but, to be honest, I haven't studied Gaussian Elimination to solve system of equations so I was kinda hoping to solve it in the augmented matrix approach (which is what I was expected to do)

Comment: That is, precisely, what I wrote above ;) You have the $3\times 2$ augmented matrix of a system of two equations and two variables ($x$ and $y$). The difference now is that you have to keep $z$ when solving the system. For instances, from the second row you have $$-3y=1+2z \Rightarrow y=\frac{1+2z}{-3}.$$

Comment: Oh...alright. I conpletely misinterpreted what you wrote above. Sorry about that. I never considered shifting z to the right hand side but it seems like a pretty neat way to go about this sum. Thanks!